# How to import NativeBase 2.2.0 to ReactNative project?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I am a newbie in ReactNative development and I am trying to import NativeBase 2.2.0 to my project. I follow this instruction 
[Getting started](http://rawgit.com/GeekyAnts/native-base-docs/v2.0/_book/docs/GetStarted.html)

Steps:

```
 $react-native init MyProject
    $cd MyProject
    $react-native run-android
```

After successful install the app on my phone, I try to install NativeBase

```
$npm install native-base --save
```

> > native-base@2.3.3 postinstall \MyProject e_modules\native-base
> >     node addEjectScript.js
>
> ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>   ─────────────┐ │ NativeBase 2.0 has been succesfully installed!
>                │ │ Run `node node_modules/native-base/ejectTheme.js` to copy over theme confi d variables. │ │ Head over to the docs for
>   detailed information on how to make changes to t heme.        │
>   └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>   ─────────────┘ npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You
>   should commit this f
>
> npm WARN native-base@2.3.3 requires a peer of react@>=16.0.0-alpha.3
>   but non  installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm
>   WARN native-base@2.3.3 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.46.0 but
>   none installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
>   native-base-shoutem-theme@0.2.1 requires a peer of react-native@>=0 0
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN native-base-shoutem-theme@0.2.1 requires a peer of
>   react@>=16.0.0-a .3 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself.
>
> - native-base@2.3.3 added 22 packages, removed 625 packages and updated 91 packages in 78.962s

But when I go to `Install Peer Dependencies` step, I got error

```
$react-native link
```

> Command `link` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install`
>   and you are inside a react-native project.

Then I try :

```
 $npm install react
    npm WARN react-native@0.49.5 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-beta.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
    react@16.0.0 added 115 packages, removed 15 packages and updated 1 package in 20.176s


 $npm install react-native
    npm WARN deprecated connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN react-native@0.49.5 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-beta.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
+ react-native@0.49.5
added 115 packages, removed 15 packages and updated 1 package in 189.374s

$react-native link
 Scanning folders for symlinks in ..\ReactNative\MyAsset\node_modules (40ms)
rnpm-install info Linking assets to ios project
rnpm-install info Linking assets to android project
rnpm-install info Assets have been successfully linked to your project
```

I got error when try to install app.

```
 $react-native run-android
       React packager ready.
    Loading dependency graph, done.
    Bundling `index.js`  [development, non-minified]  0.0% (0/418), failed.
    error: bundling failed: Error: Cannot find module 'AccessibilityInfo' (While processing preset: "MyProject\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-native\\react-native-implementation.js")
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
        at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.get AccessibilityInfo [as AccessibilityInfo] (MyProject\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js:19:36)
        at MyProject\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\lodash\_baseClone.js:145:23
        at arrayEach (MyProject\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
        at baseClone (MyProject\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\lodash\_baseClone.js:142:3)
        at cloneDeepWith (MyProject\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\lodash\cloneDeepWith.js:37:10)
```

Environment 
- node --version 
v6.11.5 
- react-native --version 
react-native-cli: 2.0.1 
react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory 
- npm --version 
5.5.1

Did I do something wrong or missing something here?
Anyone can help? 
Thanks.

Comment: Anyone can help. I still stuck at this. It's pissing me off  orz. It's seem so complicate to configure environment, right ?

Answer (score 1):

native-base@2.3.3 added 22 packages, removed 625 packages and updated 91 packages in 78.962s

it's odd. I'm working with native-base but didn't see this before.

run `npm install` after installing native base again.

if it not worked run `npm install react` and `npm install react-native`

it should work.

Comment: I did the same steps as you said and  installed app successfully. But I still get the error when try 'react-native link'. I have stuck at this for few days.

Comment: check your node_modules/react/package.json and node_modules/react-native/package.json and let me know version of these packages

Comment: I tried 'npm install react' and 'npm install react-native'  after that 'react-native  link' work. But when I tried 'react-native run-android' then I got error ==> { Bundling index.js [development, non-minified] 0.0% (0/418), failed. error: bundling failed: Error: Cannot find module 'AccessibilityInfo' (While processing preset: "MyProject\\node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\react-nat‌​ive\\react-native-im‌​plementation.js") } . I edited my question. Could you see it Thanks

Comment: after installing react-native try `react-native upgrade` and then `react-native run-android`